# Why is there a difference between creating superuser and signing up to create user in django?

Tags: python, django

I am implementing membership using django custom user model and custom register serializer. But when I finished the implementation and tested it, there was a little problem, so I want to ask. It is the I from the console python manage.py, and when I was running a command createsuperuser sign up when to membership to access the results page with each other. Here are some pictures.

[image]

If I sign up like this,

[image]

password is not encrypted by pbkdf2_sha256 method, username has nothing, and profile has default_image

[image]

However, the superuser created as a command in the console not only enters username and profile image normally, but password is normally encrypted in the pbkdf2_sha256 method. I hope that the user who joined the signUp page will be normal user name and profile like superuser and the encryption will be the same. How can I modify my code? Here's my code.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, email, profile, userName, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            userName=userName,
            profile=profile,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, userName, profile):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            userName=userName,
            profile=profile,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.set_password(password)

        user.save()
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    profile = models.ImageField(default='default_image.jpeg')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer, TokenRefreshSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from allauth.account import app_settings as allauth_settings
from allauth.utils import email_address_exists
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from allauth.account.utils import setup_user_email
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class customRegisterSerializer (serializers.Serializer) :
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    userName = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    profile = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and email_address_exists(email):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    _("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
        return email

    def validate_password (self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'password': self.validated_data.get('password', ''),
            'userName': self.validated_data.get('userName', ''),
            'profile' : self.validated_data.get('profile', ''),
        }

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get('password'))
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])
        user.save()
        return user

class customTokenObtainPairSerializer (TokenObtainPairSerializer) :
    def validate (self, attrs) :
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
        del(data['refresh'])
        del(data['access'])
        data['token_type'] = 'bearer'
        data['access_token'] = str(refresh.access_token)
        data['expires_at'] = str(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=6))
        data['refresh_token'] = str(refresh)
        data['refresh_token_expires_at'] = str(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30))

        return data

class customTokenRefreshSerializer (TokenRefreshSerializer) :
    def validate (self, attrs) :
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        refresh = RefreshToken(attrs['refresh'])
        data['token_type'] = 'bearer'
        data['access_token'] = str(refresh.access_token)
        data['expires_at'] = str(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=6))
        data['refresh_token'] = str(refresh)
        data['refresh_token_expires_at'] = str(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30))
        del(data['access'])

        return data

class userProfileSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    profile = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)
    class Meta :
        field = ('email', 'userName', 'profile')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I also faced this error and found that due to mismatch name in template and view it return None**

> create_user set password for None
> Trace your code
> **SO It got resolved in my case **

**In your case use:**

```
def create_user(self, email, profile, userName, password):
    email=self.normalize_email(email),
    *user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)*
    userName=userName,
    profile=profile,
    
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

Instead of

```
def create_user(self, email, profile, userName, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        password=password,
        userName=userName,
        profile=profile,
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```